# Is there any equivalent std::algorithm similar to std::map::lower_bound for std::tr1::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, unordered-map

Is there any equivalent std::algorithm similar to std::map::lower_bound for std::tr1::unordered_map ?

Comment: What's the use of lower_bound, if the sequence is unordered?

Comment: Basically I want to use the already existing container in my code which is std::tr1::unordered_map without copying it to std::map.

Comment: At a higher level, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 7):

No, there is none,  since `std::unordered_map` is not an ordered container.

`std::lower_bound` exists,  but it only works with ordered containers:

> *Requires:* The elements `e` of `[first,last)` shall be partitioned with respect to the expression `e < value` or `comp(e, value)`.

*C++11, [lower.bound] (§25.4.3.1)*

Comment: `std::unordered_map` satisfies `ForwardIterator`. `std::lower_bound` requires its iterator to satisfy `ForwardIterator`. What I am missing?

Comment: @Rakete1111: "The range `[first, last)` must be at least partially ordered, i.e. partitioned with respect to the expression element `< value` or `comp(element, value)`. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion, as does a range resulting from a call to `std::partition`."